# IF condition in onchange attribute

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I want to trigger controller method only when text box gets cleared out. I tried to use IF condition in `onchange` but it throws out error `Uncaught Uncaught error in markup://aura:valueChange [Cannot read property 'config' of undefined]`

```
<lightning:input type="text" name="searchBox" label="{!v.searchLabel}" 
 value ="{!v.searchString}" onchange ="{!if(v.searchString == null,c.onEmptyInput,''}"/>
```

I know I can just use `onchange={!c.onEmptyInput}` and then check if `searchString` is null in controller method and write my logic based on that. But I want to know if `IF` statements can be used to call controller methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know I can just use `onchange={!c.onEmptyInput}` and then check if `searchString` is `null` in controller method and write my logic based on that.

You should stick to this approach instead of using any conditional logic here. Additionally, your `onchange` will not even trigger if the input is empty.

With what you are trying to do, you won't be able to use a conditional statement here, as it will not work. For `onchange` to work, you will need to explicitly mention a controller function in format of:

```
onchange="{!c.myFunction}"
```

Values anything other than this format will have no effect on the event handler (I can confirm this with a quick test). In this case even if your `if` condition evaluates correctly (this is not correctly written though in its current form and you will get a compile time error), you will only get a value, which will not be of the same format as what is expected.